# transfer lambda to another lambda with different type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Suppose I have two functions testMethodOnInt and testMethod, they both take std::function as parameter. One is on type `int`, the other is on type `pair<string, int>`.

Is there a way to keep `testMethod(lambda);` call in main function, but modify `testMethod` to use `testMethodOnInt`, so it can print every value in the map.

**There are a few additional requirements:**

1. `testMethod` has to been called in the main function, while `testMethodOnInt` can't be called in main function
2. `testMethod` can't access the map directly, it has to call `testMethodOnInt`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int> m { {"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}, }; 

// This method can't be called in main directly
void testMethodOnInt(std::function<void(int)> f2) {
    for(const auto& item : m) {
       f2(item.second);
    }
}

// this method doesn't have access to the map, but can call testMethodOnInt method 
void testMethod(std::function<void(std::pair<std::string, int>)> f) {
   ..
}

int main()
{   
    auto lambda = [](std::pair<std::string, int> x) { std::cout << x.second << std::endl; };
    testMethod(lambda);
}
```

Comment: After reading the question five times I'm still not quite sure what the question is asking. I feel like I almost grasp the essence of what the question is, but everytime I think I got it, it slips through my fingers. What does "transfer lambda to another lambda with different type" mean? Can you explain, in prose, exactly how you expect your new function to work, step by step?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Its like a magic trick on my mind.

Comment: I think this question makes more sense the other way around: to modify `testMethodOnInt` to use `testMethod`, instead. Then things suddenly make perfect sense. But not the other way around. It's amazing how turning everything inside out changes utter chaos to cold, hard logic. But, if utter chaos is, indeed, the preferred approach then it'll always remain utter chaos.

Comment: Oh, thanks for reading this question, @SamVarshavchik, I was about to explain that. I have updated the question, and you are right, that's the ask from me. (I tried to add more information but looks like it complicates the question :)

Comment: If, as you say, the method in question "doesn't have access to the map", then how do you propose it could possibly access each `int`'s string key, to forward it to `f`. I presume that's what your intent is. If so, this is not possible, C++ does not work this way. If you're asking how to call `f`, but with an empty string as each value's key, then the given answer will work.

Comment: @samvarshavchik you are right, if I need the key, it’s not possible. Here I only want the value, so the given answer will work for my case

Comment: That's an important detail that should've been included in the question. Details matter. There were several ways to interpret what's asked, and it was completely unclear. If this was clear from the beginning, then you would've gotten the very obvious answer much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `f` with a lambda and forward it to `testMethodOnInt`.

```
void testMethod(std::function<void(std::pair<std::string, int>)> f) {
  testMethodOnInt([&](int x) { f({"", x}); });
}
```

Comment: Galaxy-brained solution